# MinGW GCC compiler in Dymola seems to be unable to load external DLLs

Tags: gcc, dll, mingw, modelica, dymola

I am working with Modelica models in the Modelica Buildings Library that call an external DLL containing C code. When using a Visual Studio compiler in Dymola, the models compile and simulate successfully without errors. However, when I use a MinGW GCC compiler in Dymola, the models fail to compile and I get the error: `` undefined reference to `ffd_dll' ``, where `ffd_dll` is the entrance to the code contained in the external DLL.

32-bit and 64-bit versions of the DLL are located in `modelica_path/Buildings/Resources/Library/win32` and `modelica_path/Buildings/Resources/Library/win64`, respectively. This library directory, `modelica_path/Buildings/Resources/Library`, is defined in the Modelica model as well. My operating system is Windows 10 and this problem occurs using both Dymola 2020 and Dymola 2021.

I have verified the MinGW compiler as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NEhS.png). This compiler also works fine when using Modelica models that do not call external DLLs.

I believe the issue is the DLLs cannot be located when using the MinGW compiler, so I am wondering if there is something more I need to do to set up the compiler to help it locate the DLL.

Also, there is a reason I am interested in using the MinGW compiler in Dymola when the Visual Studio compiler works perfectly well. I have compiled another DLL containing mixed C and Fortran code using MinGW GCC and GFortran, but have run into issues using this DLL when using a Visual Studio compiler in Dymola. I thought using a MinGW GCC compiler in Dymola would be more appropriate since the DLL was compiled with a MinGW GCC compiler.

Comment: First of all: please copy and past the text of your error instead of using an image.

Basic question is always: are you sure you're not mixing 32-bit and 64-bit, but that seems to be okay here.

I have a hunch your error is complaining about the symbol not being found as if it's looking for a statically linked library. You should check if `dllimport` is used in the header file that defines `ffd_dll`

Comment: Thank you for your response @BrechtSanders. I have edited the header file that defines ffd_dll such that I now declare this function like so:  `__declspec(dllimport) int *ffd_dll(CosimulationData *cosim);`. However, I now receive a similar error: `undefined reference to '_imp__ffd_dll'`. In the header file that defines this function within the DLL, it is declared similarly as: `__declspec(dllexport) int ffd_dll(CosimulationData *cosim);`. Perhaps this is not the correct way to do this.